# Beautifulsoup get element with the same class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble parsing HTML elements with "class" attribute using Beautifulsoup.

The html code is like this :

```
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Model</div>
        <div class="item-content">XPANDER 1.5L GLX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Transmission</div>
        <div class="item-content"> MT </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Engine Capacity (cc)</div>
        <div class="item-content">1499 cc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Fuel</div>
        <div class="item-content">Bensin </div>
    </div>
```

I nead to get data (XPANDER 1.5L GLX, MT, 1499, Gasoline)

I try with script *detail.find(class_='item-content')* just only get **XPANDER 1.5L GLX**

please help

Comment: you should use `find_all`. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Comment: I need each field so that it can be included in each field title. Just like (XPANDER 1.5L GLX, MT, 1499, Gasoline) . almost give up with beutifulsoup. please help

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find_all()` or `.select()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Model</div>
        <div class="item-content">XPANDER 1.5L GLX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Transmission</div>
        <div class="item-content"> MT </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Engine Capacity (cc)</div>
        <div class="item-content">1499 cc</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
        <div class="item-name">Fuel</div>
        <div class="item-content">Bensin </div>
    </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

items = [
    item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.find_all(class_="item-content")
]

print(*items)
```

Prints:

```
XPANDER 1.5L GLX MT 1499 cc Bensin
```

---

Or:

```
items = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in soup.select(".item-content")]
```

Comment: amazing, but i need (XPANDER 1.5L GLX, MT, 1499, Gasoline).i need each field. please help

Comment: @TrijokoBisa `items` is a list. So `print(items[0])` will print first element, `print(items[1])` second element and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot, i try with print(item) everythings is ok. solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
items = [item.text for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "item-content"})]
```

find_all retreives all occurences

Comment: i need each field so that it can be included in each field title. please help